# Qt QWebView The root certificate of the certificate chain is self-signed, and untrusted

Tags: qt, ssl, ssl-certificate

In my Qt app I open a QWebView that makes an AJAX request to a server through https.

some code:

```
m_network = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
...
QObject::connect(m_network, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QNetworkReply*, const QList<QSslError> & )),
                    this, SLOT(sslErrorHandler(QNetworkReply*, const QList<QSslError> & )));
```

and the handler:

```
void MainWin::sslErrorHandler(QNetworkReply* qnr, const QList<QSslError> & errlist) {

    foreach (QSslError err, errlist) {
        qDebug() << "ssl error: " << err << endl;
    }

    qnr->ignoreSslErrors();
}
```

I get the following error on a certain Windows XP machines, not all of them, some work just fine. I have OpenSSL installed on every machine.

```
Debug: ssl error:  "The root certificate of the certificate chain is self-signed, and untrusted"
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the date and time in the clock on your computer.

Some security software intercept secure connections and send their own certificate.

Some examples are ESET and Bitdefender.

ESET setup -> advanced setup -> extend web and email tree -> SSL
SSL protocol: Do not scan SSL protocol